# How to do rb.AddForce but for 2D? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, game-development

I am making a 2D game where you control a shield and you have to block falling obstacles from reaching base. I know that to move something you use `rb.addforce`. However, when I do the same for 2D it doesn't work. I imagine that instead of using a Vector3 you use a Vector2, but it gives me these 2 errors: `Assets\Movement.cs(16,25): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2'` and this one: `Assets\Movement.cs(16,25): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2'` for each time I write the line. Here is my full code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Collider2D collider;

    public float moveSpeed = 0.1f;

    private void Update() 
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(0f, moveSpeed);
            Debug.Log("w");
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(0f, moveSpeed);
            Debug.Log("s");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new `Vector2` in `rb.AddForce (new Vector2(0,moveSpeed));`

Here is the updated code:

```
 public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Rigidbody2D rb;
        public Collider2D collider;

        public float moveSpeed = 0.1f;

        private void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKey("w"))
            {
                rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, moveSpeed));
                Debug.Log("w");
            }

            if (Input.GetKey("s"))
            {
                rb.AddForce(new Vector2 (0f, moveSpeed));
                Debug.Log("s");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't this basically exactly what I already said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62548432/7111561)? ^^

Comment: @JMasterBoi could you consider using my answer which said exactly that but 1 hour earlier?

Answer (score 1):

[`Rigidbody2D.AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html) doesn't take two `float` parameters but rather as usual a `Vector2` and a `ForceMode2D` where the latter has a default value of `ForceMode2D.Force` if you don't pass it in.

So your code should rather be

```
//          = new Vector2 (0,1) * moveSpeed
//          = new Vector2 (0, moveSpeed)
rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * moveSpeed);

...

// I assume in the second case you rather want to go down so
//           = new Vector2 (0, -1) * moveSpeed
//           = new Vector2 (0, -moveSpeed)
rb.AddForce(Vector2.down * moveSpeed);
```

Btw I would rather not `Debug.Log` every frame in `Update` it's pretty expensive.